# Looping FTP in a bash script

Tags: bash, loops, ftp

I need to constantly send files automatically over FTP. Originally I just had a script that fed into stdin for FTP, but realized that for each time I do this, I need to close then reopen the connection between server and client. Reconnection takes more time than actually sending the file. I've tried avoiding this by making a separate script to open the connection and running a script to send the file in a loop.

Here's the issue: after running the connection script, ftp automatically disconnects. Here's the connection script.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='192.168.1.2'
USER='user'
PASSWD='passwd'

echo "open $HOST
user $USER $PASSWD
ascii" > /tmp/ftp.$$

ftp -ivn < /tmp/ftp.$$ >> ftplog.txt
rm /tmp/ftp.$$
```

and this is the script to send the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "put localfile.txt remotfile.txt" > /tmp/ftp.$$
ftp -ivn < /tmp/ftp.$$ >> ftplog.txt
rm /tmp/ftp.$$
```

The connection script opens the connection fine but closes it again once it runs. Any way to avoid this?

I should clarify that I am not uploading a list of files, but a single file that is updated by another script and is sent after update. This one file is sent over and over in as close to real time as possible.

Comment: Hi, it seems unnecessary complexity is throwed inside here. Why having 3 script execute one after another with input/output redirection, while you could just parametrize a script with a built-in function to FTP?

Comment: Can you go into a little more depth? I'm open to other solutions, just trying to avoid constantly closing and reopening my connection each time a file is sent.

Comment: You can use FTP's mput to upload many files in one connection, but in order to automate this all files should be in a single folder

Answer (score 1):

you can upoload all files in a folder with the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='your host'
USER="your user"
PASSWD="pass"
REMOTEPATH='/upload'

function usage(){
    echo "Usage $0 <folder>"
}

function ftp(){
  ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
  quote USER $USER
  quote PASS $PASSWD
  cd $REMOTEPATH
  lcd $1
  mput *
  quit
  END_SCRIPT
}

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
    then
        usage
    else
        ftp $1 
        exit 0
fi
```

Comment: This would be a great option if I were looking to upload many different files. However, I'm looking to upload a single file each time it is updated by a different program - Essentially synchronizing a file on the remote machine with a file on the local machine. It's not a group of files being uploaded simultaneously, but a single file being sent at many different points in time.

Comment: Then why not use rsync?

Comment: rsync is definitely still an option. I think rsync may not be as fast as ftp, even with ftp opening and closing connections, simply because ssh is going to slow things up. I will time them both and find out.

Comment: Instead of using `mput` in the `ftp` function, use `get` or `put`. The standard way to control `ftp` is to create a *netrc* script either through an actual file, or in some versions of `ftp`, through a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) as demonstrated. Better would be to use [scp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/scp.1.html) which is more secure since the password is not passed as plaintext over the network. You need to setup [ssh key pairs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html), so `scp` doesn't ask for a password.

Comment: I should note that the files being sent are extremely small, so compression/transmission times are negligible compared to the time required to establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to upload all files added today to remote ftp server.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'

# Local directory where the files are stored.
cd "/local/directory/from where to upload files/"

# To get all the files added today only.
TODAYSFILES=`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1`


# remote server directory to upload backup
REMOTEDIR="/directory on remote ftp computer/"

for FILENAME in ${TODAYSFILES[@]}; do
  ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
  ascii
  user $USER $PASSWD
  prompt
  cd $REMOTEDIR
  put $FILENAME
  bye
  EOT
done
```