# Loop between 2 ftps to retrieve files using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for ip in ips:  
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(ip)
    ftp.login(username, passwd)
```

Please help me loop between a few ftp locations to retrieve files from them.

Comment: ftps = [] ftps = ["x.x.x.x","y.y.y.y"] ftp_list =[] for ftpi in ftps: if ftpi == "x.x.x.x": username = "abc" passwd = "1234" ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftpi) ftp.login(username, passwd) ftp_list.append(ftp) elif ftpi == "y.y.y.y": username = "efgh" passwd = "123456" ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftpi) ftp.login(username, passwd) ftp.cwd("/out/qrf/") ftp_list.append(ftp) print ftp_list

Comment: however, I am not able to make a list of the logged in FTPs.........please help

Comment: I need to iterate through different FTPs

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any error or output. What exactly is your problem. There is a lot of working solutions like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342420/1012759
or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/ftp-bulk-download-and-rename .

Just write a function and then pass the arguments to it in for loop.

Comment: I am just not able to take different FTP connections in a loop. Just not able to figure out the function. Can you please help me with a simple layout.

Comment: ftps = []
ftps = ["x.x.x.x","y.y.y.y"]

ftp_list =[]
for ftpi in ftps:

 if ftpi == "x.x.x.x":
  username = "abc"
  passwd = "1234"
  ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftpi)
  ftp.login(username, passwd)
  ftp_list.append(ftp)
  
  
    
  
 elif ftpi == "y.y.y.y":
  
  username = "efgh"
  passwd = "123456"
  ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftpi)
  ftp.login(username, passwd)
  ftp.cwd("/out/qrf/")
  ftp_list.append(ftp)
  
 
print ftp_list

Comment: this how I looped between the ftps.......however I am not able to get hold of the files in them